# How to execute these all of these classes

Tags: python, class

I am having trouble printing all this. what am I missing?

```
class Animal():
    def __init__(self):
        print("I am an animal")

class Mammal(Animal):
    def __init__(self,mouse, dog, cat):
        self.mouse = mouse
        self.dog = dog
        self.cat = cat
        print("I am a mammal")

    def Mouse_mammal(self):
        mouse = "I am a mouse"
        print(mouse)

    def Dog_mammal(self):
        print("I am a dog")

    def Cat_mammal(self):
        print("I am a cat")

class Reptile(Animal):
    def __init__(self):
        print("I am a reptile")

    def Alligator_reptile(self):
        print("I am a reptile")

    def Lizard_reptile(self):
        print("I am a lizard")
```

Comment: You are missing code that actual creates instances of these classes

Answer (score 0):

After defining your classes, you must create a instance of each class. The you must call each method of each class. eg.

```
animal = Animal()
mammal = Mammal()

mammal.Mouse_mammal('mouse', 'dog', 'cat')
mammal.Dog_mammal()
mammal.Cat_mammal()

reptile = Reptile()
reptile.Alligator_reptile()
reptile.Lizard_reptile()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code does nothing.

I mean, it does declare and define a lot of things, but it *does* nothing.

Basically, what your code does is a description of your situation: you have animals, that can be mammals or reptiles... But that's all.

If you want to have some feedback, like printing, you have to make these things act. You have defined **classes**, and you have to **instantiate** them. This is done as follows:

```
>>> lizard = Reptile()
>>> lizard.Lizard_reptile()
"I am a lizard"
```

However, you seem a bit confused with what you're doing, judging by the use of caps for method names. In your code, `Lizard_reptile` and `Alligator_reptile` are **methods**, and not classes. This means that there cannot exist an object that is a lizard, for instance.

You seem to want to use inheritance, and create a `Lizard` and a `Alligator` classes, that inherit from `Reptile`, which is a logical conception of this problem.

Well, this is done just as you did with `Reptile` and `Mammals`, that inherit from `Animal`.